# Add a number to an ArrayList by sorting

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Include a method `addEventToTimeline` that will be passed an `Event`.  When an `element` is added to the `ArrayList` of events, it should be put in the correct place in the list. The elements in events should always be in chronological order.

Use similar logic and code to what we used yesterday to add an `Event` into the 
correct place in the list.  (`Event`s are compared using `compareTo`.)

My code looks like this so far. I know it's wrong but I have no idea where to go from here.

```
public void addEventToTimeline(Event a){
    for(int i = 0; i <events.size(); i++){
        if(a.compareTo(events.get(i))<0);
        events.add(i+1, events.get(i));
        events.set(i, a);


    }

}
```

}

Comment: Which language? Javascript? If so, add the appropriate language tag.

Comment: Java, I added it. Thanks.

Comment: Read the javadoc of List.add(): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-. Read the javadoc of Collections.binarySearch(): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-

Answer (score 0):

Are you forced to use an ArrayList ? I would use a tree for this kind of problem. Here's what you should do with an ArrayList solution:

1. Find the correct place for the new Event (O(n) if the arrayList is unsorted, Log(n) if it is sorted - using Binary Search
2. Put the Event in its place, and move all the subsequent Events one position to the right ( O(n) )

I would use a more advanced data structure for this. For example if all you want is the min Event each time use a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure))

If you need a global order, use a [BST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) , or even better, a [red black tree](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips-100019/24-java-lang/1904-red-black-tree-implementation-in-java.html)

[This post on StackExchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/930/adding-elements-to-a-sorted-array) can also be useful